# RegCreateKeyExA function returning ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (error code 87)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, registry

I am encountering an error code of value 87, which correlates to ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER as per [Winerror.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-). The function call to the `RegCreateKeyExA()` function is as follows:

`RegCreateKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software/Test/RegistryTest", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &createdKey, &dispositionValueOfCreatedKey);`

where,

`createdKey` is a variable of `HKEY` type declared as `HKEY createdKey;`

`dispositionValueOfCreatedKey` is a variable of `DWORD` type declared as `DWORD dispositionValueOfCreatedKey;`

At the moment, I have not tried and am unaware of any means to mitigate this error as, I believe, the above function call satisfies all the parameter requirements mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexa) MSFT documentation of the function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The component separator is a backslash (`\ `), not a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: As @IInspectable points out,you need a backslash separator, which you have to specify using a **double** backslash to avoid 'escaping' the next character.

Comment: @IInspectable whoops! silly me! Guess I really need some time off!

Comment: @AdrianMole "*... which you have to specify using a **double** backslash to avoid 'escaping' the next character...*" - unless you use a [raw string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/), then no double-up escaping is necessary, eg: `RegCreateKeyExA(..., R("Software\Basil\RegistryTest"), ...);`

Comment: @hecate You can post an answer and accept it for clear and helpful for other people are searching on this issue, instead of adding solution in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components of the registry path must be separated by a backslash (`\`), which must be escaped to avoid escaping the next corresponding character if the path string is not specified as a raw string literal as `R("dir_1\dir_2\dir_3")` (exclusive to MSFT compilers) or `R"dir_1\dir_2\dir_3"`.