# How can return json string when value contains quotation mark (")

Tags: c++, json

Imagine that I have this json:

```
{
  "a":"b"
}
```

If I have a function in C++ that returns this json in string format, such as `std::string getjson()`, it would return stringified version of this json like:

```
"{\"a\":\"b\"}"
```

To be complete:

```
std::string getjson()
{
    return "{\"a\":\"b\"}";
}

myfavourite_jsonparser.parse(getjson());
```

This works.

Now imagine that the value of key in json contains a `"`:

```
{
  "a":"\"b"
}
```

How could I return this from `std::string getjson()` function?

Comment: `"{\"a\":\"\\\"b\"}"` or `R"({"a":"\"b"})"`?

Comment: Consider using [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string) when embedding things in strings.

Comment: Or even better use a json library rather than trying to construct it by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you escape a quote with a backslash (`\"` results in `"`), a backslash can be used to escape backslashes as well. So `\\` results in `\`.

So if you want to output `\"`, then escape like this: `\\\"`.