# how can I pass a parameter to the system function with quotes?

Tags: c++, linux, system

I'm trying to reduce columns of top funcion and save it into a file but I don't know how do it using system() function with quotes. I'm doing it like this:

`system("top -b n1 | grep \"^ \" | awk '{ printf(\"%s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n\", $1, $2, $8, $3, $9, $10, $12); }' >> file`

I'm pretty sure the problem is with the quotes, can someone help me?

Comment: what makes you think it is the quotes? What happens when you compile and run the code?

Comment: If you are using c++11 or greater you can use raw string literals to avoid having to escape. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string)

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your quotes. First, you are missing a closing `")`, and I'm not sure how you are trying to use the variable `file` but it looks like you are mixing up strings with variables. Make sure that the variable  `file` is indeed used as a variable when you add it to your command string. Lastly, you are escaping `\n` wrong which messes up your output. You should escape that backslash, so you need to type  `\\n` to wind up with `\n` in your awk command.

This should work:

```
string file = "test.txt"; 
system((string("top -b n1 | grep \"^ \" | awk '{ printf(\"%s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\\n\", $1, $2, $8, $3, $9, $10, $12); }' >> ") + file).c_str());
```