# cpprestsdk fails parsing with backslash

Tags: c++, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

```
  wstring  str1 = L"\"address\":\"test \ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""
  wstring  str2 = L"\"address\":\"test \\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""
  wstring  str3 = L"\"address\":\"test \\\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""
  wstring  str4 = L"\"address\":\"test \\\\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""
```

JSON parsing fails in first three cases and returns
`address=test \\ 0001`
`type=Float`
But I want only one backslash in address, How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The c++ parser eats one layer of backslashes, and JSON expects to see a double backslash if you want the final parsed value to contain a single backslash. You can use raw C++ string literals to get rid of one level of escaping, if you want.

Comment: I'm already using L for wide characters string

Comment: No, that is something different still. See item 6 at [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) or [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string)

Answer (score 0):

I every language you need to escape certain characters within a string literal. In C++ the escape sequence starts with a `\` and followed by an escaped value for the char to be represented.

In `str1 = "\"address\":\"test \ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""` the `\`  (the one before 00001) is `\040` (`040` is for the white space space) which is an unknown escape sequence so this escape sequence is ignore, and will result in:

`"address":"test \ 00001","type":"Float"`

For `str2 = "\"address\":\"test \\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""` the `\\` is a vlaid escape sequnce for `\` and that results in:
`"address":"test \ 00001","type":"Float"`

For `str3 = "\"address\":\"test \\\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""` the `\`  (the one before 00001) is the same as in the first case. And `\\` before it is valid. So it results in:

`"address":"test \\ 00001","type":"Float"`

For `str4 = "\"address\":\"test \\\\ 00001\",\"type\":\"Float\""` the escape squeence is correct and resutls in:

`"address":"test \\ 00001","type":"Float"`

This string is then once again pares by the JSON parse, there `\` is also used as beginning of the escape sequence, so after parsing this resulting `"address":"test \\ 00001","type":"Float"`, you will get `"test \ 00001"` for `address`.

That's one of the reasons why you don't want to build a JSON representation of data manually.