# arduino ide - concatenate string and integer to char

Tags: c++, string, char, integer, concatenation

The following code should work for strings, but does not seem to be working for char arrays.

```
char *TableRow = "
           <div class = \"divTableRow\">
           <div class = \"divTableCell\">" + j + "< / div >
           <div class = \"divTableCell\" id=\"tm" + i + "b" + j + "\">0< / div >
           <div class = \"divTableCell\" id=\"sm" + i + "b" + j + "\">0< / div >
           < / div >
           ";
```

I get the message that there is a missing terminating `"` character. What I am trying to accomplish is to concatenate the text and the variables (`int j` and `int i`) to the char array. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) without  prefix in C++ are of type `const char[N]`. For example `"abc"` is a `const char[4]`. Since they're arrays, you can't concatenate them just like how you don't do that with any other array types like `int[]`. `"abc" + 1` is pointer arithmetic and not the numeric value converted to string then append to the previous string. Besides you can't have multiline strings like that. Either use **multiple string literals**, or use [raw string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56710024/995714) `R"delim()delim"`

So to get the string like that the easiest way is to use a [stream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::ostringstream s;
s << R"(
    <div class = "divTableRow">
    <div class = "divTableCell">)" << j << R"(</div>
    <div class = "divTableCell" id="tm")" << i << "b" << j << R"(">0</div>
    <div class = "divTableCell" id="sm")" << i << "b" << j << R"(">0</div>
    </div>
    )";
auto ss = s.str();
const char *TableRow = ss.c_str();
```

You can also convert the integer value to string then concat the strings. Here's an example using multiple consecutive string literals instead of raw string literal:

```
using std::literals::string_literals;

auto s = "\n"
    "<div class = \"divTableRow\">\n"
    "<div class = \"divTableCell\""s + std::to_string(j) + "</div>\n"
    "<div class = \"divTableCell\" id=\"tm" + std::to_string(i) + "b"s + std::to_string(j) + "\">0</div>\n"
    "<div class = \"divTableCell\" id=\"sm" + std::to_string(i) + "b"s + std::to_string(j) + "\">0</div>\n"
    "</div>\n"s;
const char *TableRow = s.c_str();
```

Remove `using` and the `s` suffix if you're an older C++ standard

Comment: thank you! where do I have to tipe std::ostringstream s;? i tried various locations but get `aggregate 'std::ostringstream s' has incomplete type and cannot be defined`

Comment: @sharkyenergy you need to `#include <sstream>`

Comment: thank you, one more thing, ss is not declared.. i tried to declare it as string but that fails... what type is `ss`?

Comment: it's `std::string`. You can check that easily in the IDE or in any C++ documentation like the link above. Or just use `auto` like I use