# C++ raw string with special char

Tags: c++, escaping, string-literals, rawstring

I want to output a string like this: `onclick="func()"`. So I wrote the following code:

```
  std::string s = R"(    
    onclick="func()"
    )";
```

But here two `)"` let the compiler confused.

Please forgive me if it's a silly question.

I googled but found nothing (I don't know which keyword I should use when I googled).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a [unique string outside the `()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

```
std::string s = R"anystring(    
  onclick="func()"
  )anystring";
```