# Read the student content from a File and fill the Vector using regex. And print the records in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I have tried to read the file content and trying to fill the vector using regex. But controller is not going into if condition i.e..,( if(regex_match(line,match,pattern))). Please help me here.

input.txt:

```
Name: Bhanu
RollNumber: 32
Discipline: ECE
Location: Hyderabad

Name: Raj
RollNumber: 92
Discipline: CSC
Location: Delhi
```

strucure:

```
struct Student{
    string name;
    int rollnumber;
    string discipline;
    string location;
};
void readContentFromFile(vector<Studentst> &stuVect){
    ifstream inputFile("/home/bharath/input.txt");
    if(!inputFile.is_open()){cout<<"Could not open a File"<<endl; return;}
    else{
        string line;
        regex pattern("Name: [\w+]\nRollNumber: [\d+]\nDiscipline: [\w+]\nLocation: [\w+]");
        while(getline(inputFile,line)){
            smatch match;
            cout<<__LINE__<<" line: "<<line<<endl;

            if(regex_match(line,match,pattern))
{
                cout<<__LINE__<<"Inside regex_match condition"<<endl;
                Student student;
                student.name = match[1].str();
                student.rollnumber = std::stoi(match[2].str());
                student.discipline = match[3].str();
                student.location = match[4].str();

            students.push_back(student);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    inputFile.close();
}


   int main(){
    vector<Studentst> stuVector;
    readContentFromFile(stuVector);
    displayInfo(stuVector);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: what is your specific question? What did you find when you used a debugger? Your are doing a lot at once, you should first figure out which part of the code has a problem. Is reading from the file ok? Is the vector properly populated? Is it the regex that malfunctions? If you split up those different concerns into seperate functions you can test them individually. Right now you have to rely on a debugger to find where the problem is

Comment: The question is simple. Read the content from a txt file using regex and fill in the vector. I have tried my self and used debugger. The problem is regex pattern and regex_match. The if condition regex_match is not executing. regex pattern might be wrong so need help

Comment: It is unusual to use regex to parse such a simple file format. But when you do, it is very important to verify the spelling of the keywords. Like `Roll Number` or `RollNumber`, `Discipline` or `Disciplan`.

Comment: " Read the content from a txt file using regex and fill in the vector." thats not a question. Its your taks. You didnt ask a specific question. If you want to ask us to debug the code, please try to post a [mcve]

Comment: Your code is full of typos and   your regex pattern doesn't match the file content. E.g. `Disciplan` instead of `Discipline`.

Comment: Sorry for wrong spelling. I have corrected the spelling now. Could you please check the regex pattern and regex match and the output.

Comment: The `getline` function will get one line.  The regex (which I think is malformed) is trying to match across several lines, all at once.  The single line will never match multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

There are bugs in the code sample:

- the correct escape sequence in plain C-string for backslash is double backslash '\\', and hence a correct regex token looks like "\\w", not "\w". One may use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710079) as a convenient alternative.
- to denote submatches in the regex pattern, use round brackets.
- the version of `getline` used in the code sample reads only one line per call, but we attempt to match multiple lines. Use `getline(inputFile,line, '\0')` to read the whole file at once. This version reads the text stream until the special *null* character appears that is not found in regular text files.

The solution may be implemented like this:

```
vector<Student> readStudents(const std::string& filePath) {
    ifstream inputFile(filePath);
    if (!inputFile) {
        cerr << "Failed to open " << filePath << endl;
        return {};
    }
    string fileContents;
    getline(inputFile, fileContents, '\0'); // read the whole file in fileContents
    regex entryPattern("Name: (\\w+)\nRollNumber: (\\d+)\nDiscipline: (\\w+)\nLocation: (\\w+)");
    smatch sm;
    vector<Student> students;
    // search for student entries through the file contents
    for (auto start = cbegin(fileContents); regex_search(start, cend(fileContents), sm, entryPattern);
            start = sm[0].second)
    {
        students.push_back({
            sm.str(1),
            stoi(sm.str(2)),
            sm.str(3),
            sm.str(4)
        });
    }
    return students;
}
```

To process the file line by line, it is probably better to prepare one regex pattern for each `struct` field and apply `regex_match()`.