RegEx Replace Empty Lines in C++
I want to delete blank lines in an input string using regex_replace(); however, the regular expression "^\n" isn't working in my code, even though it works when I test it on RegExr. Here is my code:
    std::string s = "filler text\n\nfiller text";

    std::regex reg("^\n");

    std::cout << s;

    s = std::regex_replace(s, reg, "");

    cout << '\n' << s;

Outputs:
filler text

filler text
filler text

filler text

Should I just resort to replacing any two newlines with just one? Then I'd have to loop until no matches are found, though. Why isn't this method working when there's seemingly nothing wrong with it?

How do you expect to find a newline at the beginning of a line?

Why do you need a regexp? Just replace \n\n with \n.

Note that even if this worked, you'd still need the loop, because regex_replace() doesn't replace overlapping matches.

@Chris Because it's an empty line, it has nothing but a newline.

@Barmar What do you mean by not replacing overlapping matches?

Does defining your regex with a raw string help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56710024

C++17: use std::regex_constants::multiline

@Barmar removing all non-overlapping empty lines can't produce new empty lines, no overlaps here...

Why has my question been closed for being a duplicate? The fact that ^ and $ match start and end of line always has no effect on my question as I already took that into account.

Oh, is that only in MSVC?

Suppose there are 4 consecutive newlines (3 blank lines). ^\n will replace the 2nd newline in each pair, so the result will be 2 consecutive newlines, so there's still a blank line.

@STerliakov It doesn't produce new lines, but it fails to remove all of the blank lines.

@Barmar Why would it only replace the 2nd of each pair? I tested your scenario on RexExr and that doesn't happen.

A sledgehammer method would be to put the string in a stringstream, read it back with getline and discard the empty lines.

@YoussefGamil I was wrong, since the anchor is a zero-width assertion, so not considered part of the match.

Reopened--the nominated dupe wasn't (even close) to an actual dupe.

Hm, @Barmar that's probably something specific to c++ regex then, sorry. Python's r'(?m)^\n' would remove all blank lines, not only some of them... That's probably equivalent to std::regex_constants::multiline mode suggested above?

@YoussefGamil Please do not use regex for this. Until we've got constexpr regex and the possibility to optimize such simple tasks as this, it will be very slow compared to just doing find/replace. Comparison

Like almost every question I've seen about regular expressions in the past ten years, this is utterly trivial if you don't use regular expressions, and, at best, tricky and obscure if you do. I've always feel that adding the regular expressions library was a mistake.

@PeteBecker Heh.  You have a problem.  You decide to use a regex.  Now you have two problems...

I do this one with <ranges>: auto refined = source | std::views::split('\n') | std::views::filter(std::not_fn(std::ranges::empty)) | std::views::join('\n') | std::ranges::to<std::string>();

Rather than dealing with "end of line", I'd just replace multiple consecutive new-lines with a single new-line:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string s = "filler text\n\nfiller text";

    std::regex reg("\n+");

    std::cout << "Before:\n";
    std::cout << s << "\nAfter:\n";

    s = std::regex_replace(s, reg, "\n");

    std::cout << '\n' << s << '\n';
}

The result looks like this:
Before:
filler text

filler text
After:

filler text
filler text

