Normal std::regex_search results in "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'"
bool checkConditionValidity(std::string str){
    std::regex pattern(R"([^()\s\w.&=])|([^=]=[^=])|([^&]&[^&])");
    return std::regex_search(str, pattern);
}

The above function results in a compile-time error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error' what():  regex_error" in a fresh VS Code installation with default compiler.
The regex pattern initially contained lookahead and lookbehind operators. After going through previous questions, I eliminated them and went ahead with the simple pattern above. But still no improvements whatsoever. I'm limited to only using custom code or std libraries like std::regex to achieve my desired result.

I just stumbled into this answer.
You just have to include extra open & close braces when forming the raw string. Replacing the pattern in my code with R"(([^()\s\w.&=])|([^=]=[^=])|([^&]&[^&]))" fixed it for me.
This worked for me. Not sure if it will for others. If some people have more context than me, Please do answer.

Of course, that's part of the syntax of raw strings. It requires parentheses around the contents. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string
