std::regex crash
I am seeing a crash during std::regex object creation. Please help in avoiding this crash.
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 
    std::string s = "top.\\u2_count.*er";
    std::regex regex(s);

}

Link https://godbolt.org/z/eYYMb4Wda

hint: error is: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'   what():  Invalid '\uNNNN' control character in regular expression . Note that double backslash \ can be tricky for the brain in regex strings. At the end of the day, it's a string escape for a single backslash \ but since it's in a regex, then that's the start for an regex escape sequence, in this case \u which is to specify a unicode value. A solution woudl be to double-escape the backslashes: std::string s = "top.\\\\u2_count.*er"; .

(my last comment  is assuming you want to match litterally a backslash followed by the letter u)

You want it be R"(top.\\u2_count.*er)".

Related to the comment above: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710024/what-is-a-raw-string

I am seeing a crash -- That isn't a crash, it is a thrown exception with a known cause, plus you didn't specify in any of the text in your question.  A crash would be that your program terminates abruptedly without any obvious causes.  For example, calling regex(s) just makes your application stop dead, no exception thrown -- that is a crash.
